# Emacs cedet semantic won't autocomplete scanf and malloc related functions

Tags: gcc, emacs, autocomplete, cedet

With this .emacs file

```
(load-file "~/Sources/cedet-1.0pre7/common/cedet.el")
(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)
;;(semantic-load-enable-semantic-debugging-helpers)

(setq senator-minor-mode-name "SN")
(setq semantic-imenu-auto-rebuild-directory-indexes nil)
(global-srecode-minor-mode 1)
(global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode 1)

(require 'semantic-decorate-include)

;; gcc setup
(require 'semantic-gcc)

;; smart complitions
(require 'semantic-ia)

(setq-mode-local c-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
                 '(project unloaded system recursive))
(setq-mode-local c++-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
                 '(project unloaded system recursive))
(setq-mode-local erlang-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
                 '(project unloaded system recursive))

(require 'eassist)

;; customisation of modes
(defun alexott/cedet-hook ()
  (local-set-key [(control return)] 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu)
  (local-set-key "\C-c?" 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol)
  ;;
  (local-set-key "\C-c>" 'semantic-complete-analyze-inline)
  (local-set-key "\C-c=" 'semantic-decoration-include-visit)

  (local-set-key "\C-cj" 'semantic-ia-fast-jump)
  (local-set-key "\C-cq" 'semantic-ia-show-doc)
  (local-set-key "\C-cs" 'semantic-ia-show-summary)
  (local-set-key "\C-cp" 'semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle)
  )
;; (add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'alexott/cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'alexott/cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'alexott/cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook 'alexott/cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'alexott/cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'erlang-mode-hook 'alexott/cedet-hook)

(defun alexott/c-mode-cedet-hook ()
 ;; (local-set-key "." 'semantic-complete-self-insert)
 ;; (local-set-key ">" 'semantic-complete-self-insert)
  (local-set-key "\C-ct" 'eassist-switch-h-cpp)
  (local-set-key "\C-xt" 'eassist-switch-h-cpp)
  (local-set-key "\C-ce" 'eassist-list-methods)
  (local-set-key "\C-c\C-r" 'semantic-symref)
  )
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'alexott/c-mode-cedet-hook)

;; hooks, specific for semantic
(defun alexott/semantic-hook ()
;; (semantic-tag-folding-mode 1)
  (imenu-add-to-menubar "TAGS")
 )
(add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'alexott/semantic-hook)

(custom-set-variables
 '(semantic-idle-scheduler-idle-time 3)
 '(semantic-self-insert-show-completion-function (lambda nil (semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu (point))))
 '(global-semantic-tag-folding-mode t nil (semantic-util-modes)))
;(global-semantic-folding-mode)

;; gnu global support
(require 'semanticdb-global)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode)

;; ctags
(require 'semanticdb-ectag)
(semantic-load-enable-primary-exuberent-ctags-support)
(global-semantic-idle-tag-highlight-mode 1)

;;; ede customization
(require 'semantic-lex-spp)
(global-ede-mode t)


;; my functions for EDE
(defun alexott/ede-get-local-var (fname var)
  "fetch given variable var from :local-variables of project of file fname"
  (let* ((current-dir (file-name-directory fname))
         (prj (ede-current-project current-dir)))
    (when prj
      (let* ((ov (oref prj local-variables))
            (lst (assoc var ov)))
        (when lst
          (cdr lst))))))

;; setup compile package
;; TODO: allow to specify function as compile-command
(require 'compile)
(setq compilation-disable-input nil)
(setq compilation-scroll-output t)
(setq mode-compile-always-save-buffer-p t)

(defun alexott/compile ()
  "Saves all unsaved buffers, and runs 'compile'."
  (interactive)
  (save-some-buffers t)
  (let* ((r (alexott/ede-get-local-var
             (or (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)) default-directory)
             'compile-command))
         (cmd (if (functionp r) (funcall r) r)))
;; (message "AA: %s" cmd)
    (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command) (or cmd compile-command))
    (compile compile-command)))

(global-set-key [f9] 'alexott/compile)

;;
(defun alexott/gen-std-compile-string ()
  "Generates compile string for compiling CMake project in debug mode"
  (let* ((current-dir (file-name-directory
                       (or (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)) default-directory)))
         (prj (ede-current-project current-dir))
         (root-dir (ede-project-root-directory prj))
         )
    (concat "cd " root-dir "; make -j2")))

;;
(defun alexott/gen-cmake-debug-compile-string ()
  "Generates compile string for compiling CMake project in debug mode"
  (let* ((current-dir (file-name-directory
                       (or (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)) default-directory)))
         (prj (ede-current-project current-dir))
         (root-dir (ede-project-root-directory prj))
         (subdir "")
         )
    (when (string-match root-dir current-dir)
      (setf subdir (substring current-dir (match-end 0))))
    (concat "cd " root-dir "Debug/" "; make -j2")))
;; (concat "cd " root-dir "Debug/" subdir "; make -j3")))

;; Example, Qt customization
;; (setq qt4-base-dir "/usr/include/qt4")
;; (setq qt4-gui-dir (concat qt4-base-dir "/QtGui"))
;; (semantic-add-system-include qt4-base-dir 'c++-mode)
;; (semantic-add-system-include qt4-gui-dir 'c++-mode)
;; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons qt4-base-dir 'c++-mode))
;; (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file (concat qt4-base-dir "/Qt/qconfig.h"))
;; (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file (concat qt4-base-dir "/Qt/qconfig-large.h"))
;; (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file (concat qt4-base-dir "/Qt/qglobal.h"))

;;; emacs-rc-cedet.el ends here
(delete-selection-mode t)
```

most of which is taken from Alex's .emacs

printf is autocompleted fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to try when a completion fails is:

```
M-x semantic-analyze-debug-assist RET
```

to see what it says.  You can then visit `stdio.h` to see what the parser thinks of the file.  If while there you do:

```
M-x bovinate RET
```

then you can search to see if scanf is there.  If not, there is probably a parsing bug, or some miscellaneous #define that isn't set up correctly.  Using the above you can usually whittle away at a header file to see where things start to break down.

Based on your description, I'm assuming you typed in something like:

```
   sc
```

and was hoping it would expand to `scanf`.

Comment: Hey, Eric, I was trying to use the ***Semantic-complete-self-insert*** bind with a dot, but it wouldn't even find the functions defined in the same file. After I run Semantic-analyze-debug-assist on the dot, I got this error, any idea why? Thank you very much

Comment: Regular completion is pretty complex, and tries a few things.  The commands will capture errors and move on silently, which is particularly useful for completions during idle time.  The debug-assist command exposes more errors to make it easier to debug what's going on.  You would have to post your error to get more help.